# dynamic css notification bar that scrolls with screen

Tags: css

I have a notification bar that is 'hiding' behind my header by default:

[image: default view]

It is only shown after an AJAX request (via jQuery animate()) to tell the user if it was successful:

[image: notification with header]

But when the user scrolled down the page and does not see the header, the way I build it at the moment, it *just hangs in the air*:

[image: notification without header]

So there are 2 cases:

1. if the user sees the header, it should be right beneath it
2. if the user does NOT see the header, it should be attached to the top of the page

And of course when the user scrolls it should move smoothly between the states.

**How would I do this? CSS only / with JS?**

Comment: Could you show us a example or screen shots? Thanks

Comment: I rewrote the question - hopefully better to comprehend now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the info bar using `position:relative` in your CSS. Get everying working in this normal state.

Then use the `scroll` event on the window in Javascript to find if the user has scrolled more than the height of the header. If this is the case, add a class to the info bar that sets it's position using `position:fixed; top:0;`.

Remove the class when the scrollTop height is less than the height of the header

Comment: Interesting. Does `position: fixed;` override `position: relative;` or would it be required to use the `!important` statement? Or does the newly added class automatically gain the highest priority?

Comment: The last declared value in the stylesheet will win - the order the classes are added in the HTML doesn't matter. If the rule you want is declared later in the stylesheet you've got no need to use !important. Or you can use a selector with higher specifity.

Comment: I totally recommend reading up on CSS inheritance, specifity and then the idea of modular CSS. It takes a little to get your head around, but it's where the power of CSS lies.

Comment: It's definitely one of my fuzzy areas, but yeah, I'll have to get around to understanding these subtleties. Will only help save me time in the long run, I imagine.